# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath error

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am getting that error with this piece of code. Can you help me figure out why.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Restaurant *restaurant = [self.restaurants objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",restaurant.Name,restaurant.Address]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does not always return you a valid cell; sometimes, it returns `nil`. In such cases you need to allocate a new instance of your cell, and then initialize it the usual way. As it currently stands, your method would return `nil` if one is returned from the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyle1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: @user1426292 Great! If the solution works for you, consider accepting it to let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and to earn a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.