# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath eror

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    CurrentCell *cell = (CurrentCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell == nil");
        cell = [[CurrentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }


    NSLog(@"the cell is %@", cell);
    Current *current = [currents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    [cell setCellWithCurrent:current];


    return cell;

}
```

I have added reuse identifier in storyboard, set delegate and datasource but still got this error:

```
    *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],          /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:5471
2013-11-04 23:47:34.206 MyApp[7417:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x394452a3 0x3333497f 0x3944515d 0x342082af 0x32773f79 0x325c50a1 0x325c5055 0x325c255d 0x325a730b 0x325be7c7 0x3257a803 0x35e4ed63 0x35e4e901 0x35e4f835 0x35e4f21b 0x35e4f029 0x325808eb 0x3941a6cd 0x394189c1 0x39418d17 0x3938bebd 0x3938bd49 0x377592eb 0x325cb2f9 0xec869 0x36bf7b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

How i show my view with table:

```
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCurrents"]) {

    MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

}
```

CurrentCell.m:

```
    #import "CurrentCell.h"


@interface CurrentCell ()

@end

@implementation CurrentCell
{
    UIColor *badgeColor;
    NSString *badgeText;
}

@synthesize topTitleLabel;
@synthesize descriptionLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


-(void) setCellWithCurrent:(Current*) current
{
    NSString *title = [current title];
    [self.topTitleLabel setText:title];
    [self.descriptionLabel setText:[current description]];


}

@end
```

PS: I do not get this error immediately, but after a quick scrolling list for some time.

Comment: is there any way setCellWithCurrent destroys the cell? Or spins off a different thread? Add another check to see if the cell == nil just before your return statement, then add a breakpoint in there to help you debug.

Comment: What's the code in `initWithStyle` of your `CurrentCell`. Do you have a xib?

Comment: Nope, i don't have a xib. atreat: updated my question, so you can see my setCellWithCurrent method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623514/uitableview-datasource-must-return-a-cell-from-tableviewcellforrowatindexpath-e)

Answer (score 1):

Use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

And remove that business about checking to see if the cell is nil.

Since your cell is a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, make sure that the cell's Class is set to you custom subclass in IB (see Identity Inspector).

Comment: That's odd because dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: is guaranteed to return a cell. From the docs: "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered."

Comment: this method is only for deployment targets of iOS 6.0 and higher

Comment: Check the cell's Class setting in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: checked this 100 times ;) everything looks ok, custom class is set. My deployment target is iOS 6.0+. Maybe I show tableView (MainViewController) in a wrong way? (updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

Try loading cell with loadNibNamed method of NSBundle.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your nib file name for CurrentCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: i  don't use xib files for cells, everything did in storyboard

Comment: In that case, please make sure that you have you set the custom cell identifier to @"Cell" from your identity inspector of the storyboard as you have used it in your code as reuse identifier. Also make sure that you have connected your delegate and dataSource accordingly for your table view.